# How to know last time action for every user?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of my user logs(my input):

```
user_id    log_category    client_ts

1 Rob      user            1455035670
2 Fred     progression     1455035345
3 Rob      design          1455035547
4 Rob      design          1455035870
5 Fred     user            1455035970
6 Fred     progression     1455035548
```

All I want is: To know the last log `client_ts` for all user_id (output):

```
user_id    client_ts

1 Rob      1455035870
2 Fred     1455035970
```

And then add to my input column names `is_leave` with factor `yes` if the last `last_log_ts < 1455035950` (output):

```
user_id    log_category    client_ts   last_log_ts   is_leave

1 Rob      user            1455035670  1455035870    yes
2 Fred     progression     1455035345  1455035970    no
3 Rob      design          1455035547  1455035870    yes
4 Rob      design          1455035870  1455035870    yes
5 Fred     user            1455035970  1455035970    no
6 Fred     progression     1455035548  1455035970    no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` we could do something like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,last_log_ts := max(client_ts), user_id][,is_leave := ifelse(last_log_ts < 1455035950,"yes","no")]
> df
#   user_id log_category  client_ts last_log_ts is_leave
#1:     Rob         user 1455035670  1455035870      yes
#2:    Fred  progression 1455035345  1455035970       no
#3:     Rob       design 1455035547  1455035870      yes
#4:     Rob       design 1455035870  1455035870      yes
#5:    Fred         user 1455035970  1455035970       no
#6:    Fred  progression 1455035548  1455035970       no
```